# Celery trying to connect to wrong broker

Tags: 14.04, python

I have a Django project on an Ubuntu EC2 node, which I have been using to set up an asynchronous using `Celery`.

I've been able to get a basic task working at the command line, using:

```
(env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~/projects/tp$ celery --app=myproject.celery:app worker --loglevel=INFO
```

However, if I run other celery commands like below I'm getting the following:

(env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~/projects/tp$ celery worker

```
Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.
```

It appears that celery thinks I'm using amqp as a broker , but I'm using redis!! I've been trying to follow http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2014/05/18/setting-up-an-asynchronous-task-queue-for-django-using-celery-redis/

The installed python packages:

```
(env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~/projects/tp$ pip freeze
amqp==1.4.6
anyjson==0.3.3
billiard==3.3.0.19
celery==3.1.17
Django==1.7.7
django-redis-cache==0.13.0
kombu==3.0.24
pytz==2015.2
redis==2.10.3
requests==2.6.0
uWSGI==2.0.10
```

/projects/tp/tp/celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os
import django
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'tp.settings')
django.setup()

app = Celery('hello_django')

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

also , in redis.conf:

```
# Specify the path for the unix socket that will be used to listen for
# incoming connections. There is no default, so Redis will not listen
# on a unix socket when not specified.
#
  unixsocket /var/run/redis/redis.sock
  unixsocketperm 777
```

tp.settings.py:

```
# CELERY SETTINGS
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'

CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'redis_cache.RedisCache',
        'LOCATION': '/var/run/redis/redis.sock',
    },
}
```

How can I get it to use Redis as the broker?

Comment: Hi, Have you found the answer to this??

Comment: does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29402447/how-to-set-celeryconfig-file-in-in-django

Answer (score 2):

You should add `-A` option when execute "celery worker" so that celery will connect to the broker you configured in your. Otherwise celery will try to connect the default broker.

Comment: Added -A but still not resolved

Comment: @LokeshTiwari why don't you ask your proper question?